# C# Web API2: simple routing with integer parameter is not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have a simple controler. I starts 2 URLs, one is working the second is not. Im using VS 2013 EXPRESS :).

http://localhost:53416/api/payments/ - works and displays "1"
http://localhost:53416/api/payments/2 - doesn't work and displays error HTTP 
Error 404.0 - Not Found ( no "2" is displayed).

**What is wrong with second action method?**

Controler's code

```
[RoutePrefix("api/payments")]
    public class MvbePaymentController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetPayments()
        {                            
            return Ok("1");
        }    
        [Route("{id:int}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetPayments(int invoiceId)
        {                        
            return Ok("2");
        }    
    }
```

WebApiCOnfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelStateAttribute());                                             

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your GetPayments code should have the parameter named **id** rather than **invoiceId**.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetPayments(int id)
    {                        
        return Ok("2");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ... Im newbie in Web API :).. a lot of work in front of me:) ..and PRACTICE  :)

Comment: The parameter in the route template have to match the name of the parameter in the method. So fyi, an other option is to change your route name:  `[Route("{invoiceId:int}")]`